MySQL 8 - All Parts of Spatial Index Must Be Null - But no nulls in column
I've added a POINT column to a rather large existing table.  I had to set it null initially as required by MySQL.  I then executed successfully:
update geoloc set geoPoint = ST_SRID( POINT( 0, 0 ), 4326)
Next, when I tried to add a spatial index to this column, I got
ERROR 1252: All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL
I tried "SELECT * from geoloc where geoPoint is null" and got 0 results.
So there are no null values in the column, but the index fails telling me I can't have a null.  What am I missing?

try:
-- Step 1: Ensure no NULL values (already done)
UPDATE geoloc SET geoPoint = ST_SRID(POINT(0, 0), 4326) WHERE geoPoint IS NULL;

-- Step 2: Modify the column to NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE geoloc MODIFY COLUMN geoPoint POINT NOT NULL;

-- Step 3: Add the spatial index
ALTER TABLE geoloc ADD SPATIAL INDEX (geoPoint);


Thank you so much. That worked.  A bit curious about the reason for having to do it this way.  But it works now, and that's all that matters
